# How to make a script run in the background, start upon system's start and not ask for password

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a script, that needs to start, when the system starts (so i put it in .bashrc) and run in the background (did that with &), but the problem is the scrip uses `rdate` command, which requires sudo to work. Can i somehow make it, so that it doesn't ever ask me for my password?

Comment: First, what are you hoping to achieve? If you merely want to synchronize your system's clock, have you tried one of the NTP methods (such as chrony)? Alternatively, rather than using sudo and worrying about asking for a password (or worse, trying to bypass that), have your tried methods that simply do not need to ask (system cron and rc.local, for example, both run as root anyhow)?

Comment: This is a part of of my assignment. I must synchronize the time with the external server, when system is idle ( no users logged in )

Comment: Have you asked your instructor for help? We should not give solutions to school assignments here. I (and others) have already pointed you in the right direction, however. I will also add "no one logged in" is contrary to how you are trying to do it: If you put it in .bashrc, it only runs when _you_ log in, so there is at least one user logged in. You will need to use another solution that does not require anyone to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a correction: calling `rdate` from `$HOME/.bashrc` only happens when you login and start `bash`, not at system startup. Read `man bash` about "Startup Files".

`/etc/rc.local` is the place for system startup tasks. That's where your `rdate` call should be placed.

Since `/etc/rc.local` is run by `root`, `sudo` isn't needed.

Comment: I didn't have rc.local, so i created it, like it's said here https://vpsfix.com/community/server-administration/no-etc-rc-local-file-on-ubuntu-18-04-heres-what-to-do/
and now my virtual machine wouldn't start

Answer (score 2):

Provided it is a short running process, place your script containing the rdate command in /etc/crontab so that it starts at @boot and is run by root.

A better way to obtain the correct time, would be by configuring the correct time zone and running a daemon that accesses time servers - for example by running chronyd, which can be started by systemd.

Comment: There's no syntax highlighting in crontab and also the script seems to not be working at all. Anything else i should know?

Comment: Try `man 5 crontab` for help on crontab. The man page is aimed at user crontabs, however. The system's `/etc/crontab` has an additional field between the time fields and the command to run--this field is where you specify the user to run as: `root` in this case.

Comment: Also note, the '5' in `man 5 crontab` is intentional: it means to display the man page from section 5 for crontab, which details the format of the crontab file. The regular `man crontab` page only details the crontab command/program, not the file format. To give an example crontab line: `1 2 3 4 5 root /bin/echo "it's 1 minute passed 2AM on Friday, April 3rd!" (Of course, nothing will actually display because the cronjob has no terminal assigned for /bin/echo to echo to...)